# Back button go to current position

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs6, flashdevelop

So I have to make a 2D game using flash. When the characters hit an object in the  GAMEPLAY SCENE, it will pop up a new QUIZ SCENE which is a quiz. After the user completes the quiz, they will click a BACK button which MUST take them back to the GAMEPLAY SCENE at the current position.

So the problem I have now is when I click the BACK button, how can I make it go back to the initial position in the GAMEPLAY SCENE.

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: when i click the BACK button, it will go back to initial postion in the GAMEPLAY SCENE.